# Correct path to FFmpeg through ssh

Tags: ssh, path, ffmpeg

I have server with CentOS 5.x X86_64 Bit. On this server there is ffmpeg installed on /root/install/ffmpeg but when i'm trying to check version with ffmpeg -version it's writing:
-bash: /usr/bin/ffmpeg: No such file or directory
How can i to redefine the path to correct or move ffmpeg to correct folder?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the directory where ffmpeg lives to your path:

https://serverfault.com/questions/102932/adding-a-directory-to-path-in-centos

Also, you should remove the ssh tag from this question.

If you don't want to add to your path you can also call ffmpeg from where it lives:

`/root/install/ffmpeg -v`